# Override standard "Save" in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

How to override standard "Save" in Lightning Experience?
I cannot even find this button in the Salesforce setup.

http://prntscr.com/om1sga

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot override this button in Classic or Lightning. Use a trigger or Process if you need to perform post-save logic.

Comment: [This blog](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/how-to-override-standard-buttons-with-lightning-component/) is misleading in the way it appears to suggest save can be overridden, but actually it isn't one available for override. There's an [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bra7AAC) for adding a warning based on some configurable criteria that would cover a lot of the related "replace save" use cases.